# mongodb server always write on disk

Tags: mongodb

I use Ubuntu 19 and latest mongodb server on this moment.
After install i create DB and added little bit data.

Config file simple

```
storage:
  dbPath: /home/user/mongodb/db

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

security:
  authorization: enabled

systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: /home/user/mongodb/log/mongod.log
    logAppend: true
```

After i used "sys-monitor" (console util - dstat) i saw this ( 1 line = 1 sec )

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzogO.png

How i can disable this write? DB not use but write happen.
My ssd not infinity.

Comment: "After i used "sys-monitor...": How did you use _sys-monitor_?

Comment: console util - dstat     http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man1/dstat.1.html

Comment: Its a Linux command. You can probably kill the command execution; is that what you want?

Comment: i don't understand that mongo server write on disk if nobody not useing db, if i disable mongo service - infinity writing on disk stoped

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved.
Need disable diagnostic.data, journal and you can set log quiet